# Redirect to /dev/null AND file?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I saw a line in a crontab tutorial like so:

`command 1>/dev/null 2>&1 | mail -s (...)`

Just curious, is there any reason the results from the command are dumped to `/dev/null`, and then dumped to `stderr` and piped to mail? It seems like the `1>/dev/null` is superflous.

Comment: other way around. stdout (1) gets dumped to null, then stderr (2) gets redirect to 1, meaning there should be nothing left to mail anyways

Comment: both stdout and stderr are being sent to /dev/null. I suspect somebody who didn't know what they were doing added the mail command onto the end to try and troubleshoot a problem

Comment: @Marc B: I should add that running this DOES in fact email the output. 
Via email, I get both `stdout` and `stderr` streams.

Comment: @StevenMorad: you'd probably get an empty mail, but there's no way that this could mail anything from that command, because stdout/stderr are being dumped to null.

Comment: @MarcB try `echo "foobar" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 | tee supposedly_empty`

Answer (score 1):

http://ss64.com/bash/tee.html

... try using tee, it can redirect to multiple outputs. For example:

```
 ls -al | tee out.txt
```

... redirects 'ls's output to out.txt, while it is still printed in stdout.

Comment: Yes, but there's no point in directing output to `/dev/null` and `foo`; you might as well just direct output to `foo` (whatever `foo` happens to be).